# Call a property conditionally on a component vue?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, components

I have a list of elements that may contain a subset of elements in them, so i have a list like this

```
<v-list>
    <v-list-group v-for="item in items" :key="item.id>
        <v-list-title :to="item.link">
            {{ item.title }}
        </v-list-title>
    </v-list-group>
</v-list>
```

and my `items` array is something like this.

```
data: function() {
    return {
        items[
            {
                id: 1,
                title: 'foo',
                link: '/dashboard/url/',
                items: []
            },
            {
                id: 2,
                title: 'bar',
                link: '/dashboard/url2/',
                items: [
                    {
                        id: 1,
                        title: 'foo',
                        link: '/dashboard/url/sub'
                    }
                ]
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

I want to add the property `:to` to the list only when `item.items.length > 0` is there a way to add a property dinamically? or to add it conditionally?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use condition here

```
<v-list-title :to="item.items.length ? item.link : null">
  {{ item.title }}
</v-list-title>
```